# UINavigationController No Back Button

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

Very simple scenario with lots of posts on this, but I'm still stuck. I have a `UITableView` that is embedded in a `UINavigationController` There is a final `UIViewController` that is supposed to be presented when the `UITableViewCell` is selected. When I wire all of this up, nothing happens on the row selection.

I can get the detail view to be presented by usind `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and referencing the segue by its id. However, there is no back button when I do this.

[image]

[image]
    class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    var configJson: JSON = []
    var config: [Tab] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        parseConfig()
    }

    func parseConfig() {
        let configParser = ConfigParser(configJson: configJson)
        config = configParser.parse()
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.config.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let tab = self.config[indexPath.row]

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = tab.title

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "contentSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "contentSegue") {
            let nextVC = segue.destination as? ContentViewController
            let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let tab = self.config[(indexPath?.row)!]
            nextVC?.tab = tab
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of other notes:
1. My cell identifer is set to 'cell' in the IB
2. My segue is set to 'show' with a identifier of 'contentSegue' in the IB
3. The segue is from the prototype cell to the Content View Controller.

I'm at a total loss. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: pls ,provide your next view controller code

Comment: There isn't any yet. It's just an empty viewDidLoad() method.

Comment: Try to remove your segue and create it again, sometimes it's helps, maybe you create it from UITabeView or Cell, not ViewController

Comment: Thanks. I 've tried that a few times.

Comment: What kind of segue did you make in the storyboard?

Comment: It's a show segue.

Comment: Are you sure you've set this up as a selection segue, and not an accessory action? You can check this by ctrl clicking on the cell in the storyboard - make sure your triggered segue is **selection**

Comment: Can you reduce this to a bare minimum project demonstrating the problem and post it for download? I'm happy to take a look at it for you. Seems like it must have something to do with "I have a UITableView that is embedded in a UINavigationController" — I need to see how you're doing that. Apparently it's not in a UITableViewController, so there may be something odd about it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've set this up as a selection segue, and not an accessory action? You can check this by ctrl clicking on the cell in the storyboard - make sure your triggered segue is selection.

Also…

As you've added the segue in your storyboard, there's no need to fire it in `didSelectRowAt` - so you can remove that func.

And, to remove your reliance on a string comparison (and remove a force unwrapped optional), try this…

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let nextVC = segue.destination as? ContentViewController, 
       let cell = sender? as UITableViewCell,
       let indexPath = tableview.indexPath(for: cell) {

        let tab = self.config[indexPath.row]
        nextVC.tab = tab
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it is a selection segue. I've edited my post. Also, I know that I shouldn't need the didSelectRowAt, but I added it because the my tap event was not registering. My hope is to be able to delete it entirely.